# how to bind a windows console application with java application?

Tags: java, console-application

i have an executable program (.exe) writen in c++ and run on windows console 
and i have a java swing applecation , so i want my java application to interact
with the console app (send input and get output) .
but how to do that ?

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
// Create the proccess in JAVA
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Name of application");

// Receive outputs from another program inside Java by a stream
InputStream ips = proc.getInputStream();

// Using the stream to get the messages from another program
String output = "";
int c = 0;
while ((c = ips.read()) != -1){
    output+= (char)c;
}

//Inputs messages into another program
OutputStream ops = proc.getOutputStream();
ops.write("an byte array");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can launch the C++ program from within the Java program which allows you to write to its standard input, and read its standard output.  Check the [Runtime](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class.