# Execute command using Java on Windows

Tags: java, batch-file, command

I want to execute a command `mspview -r "C:\\Users\\SS\\Desktop\\phantomjs-1.9.2-windows\\image.tif"`. How can I do it via Java code? I am trying to do this with a batch file. The same command when I run with the help of **RUN**.  I am getting correct output. I have executed a `.exe` program with the help of a batch file with the following code `C:\Users\SS\Desktop\phantomjs-1.9.2-windows\phantomjs.exe`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

Comment: @Jost I know how to execute a batch file from Java.I need to execute a command in **cmd**  which need to produce same result as when it is run on RUN

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking how to run shell commands in java, right?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whatever system call you want");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ProcessBuilder

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(
"C:\\PathToExe\\exe.exe","param1","param2").start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;

System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", Arrays.toString(args));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

code that is already found on stackoverflow
[Execute external program in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java)

Comment: I know this code and I can executing .exe.But the problem is that i want to start **Microsoft Office Document Imaging** which is to start OCR of an image.I can do this by executing the  **mspview -r "C:\\Users\\SS\\Desktop\\phantomjs-1.9.2-windows\\image.tif"**.But what i want pass the above command to RUN & executes it