# How to run python in java

Tags: java, python, jython

How to run file**.py** in your Java program without using Jython?
For example: 
I have JButton and I want to run python script when I click on the JButton.
What should I put in Action Preformed for the button to run python script without using Jython?

Comment: You call a python script through `RunTime`

Comment: Do you just need to run the script? Or do you want to interact and exchange variables with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the python interpreter installed in the machine where you want to do that and call this interpreter as an external command from Java.

Look at this question to know more about how perform that call: 
[Execute external program in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java)

From there:

```
String[] params = new String [2];
params[0] = PATH2_YOUR_PYTHON_SETUP + "python.exe";
params[1] = PATH2_YOUR_PYTHON_SCRIPT;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params);
```

Additionally, you can use the returned [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object from `exec` to interact with your script input/output.