# Executing an external program in Java returns "Access denied" or stops execution

Tags: java, sqlcipher

### Update 3

Progress! I wrote a CMD script which takes three parameters:

1. the absolute path to `sqlite3cipher.exe`
2. the absolute path to `testdb`
3. the absolute path to `statements.sql`

All the script does is execute the command

```
path\to\sqlite3cipher.exe path\to\testdb < path\to\statements.sql
```

This script is being called from within my Java code. And it works like a charm! At least with all the files residing in a folder in my home directory. Having the files in a subfolder of `C:\Program Files` doesn't work so there might be an issue with privileges which I have to work out with the administrator.

---

### Update 2

I've created a dummy SQL file in my home directory. The code should now read the SQL file from and write the database file to my home directory.

Again omitting `cmd /c` in the command reads and writes the first line from the SQL file but stops after that (execution of the whole program comes to a halt). 
Executing the command including `cmd /c` reads and writes every single line of the SQL file but once EOF is reached (in which case nothing will be written of course) I again get the `Access denied` message.

---

### Update 1

Taking [skarist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3817160/skarist)'s comment into account the following command (omitting `cmd /c` as it isn't mandatory for executing exe-files after all)

```
String cmdForRuntime = "\"" + prog.getAbsolutePath() + "\" \"" + fDb.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
```

which spelled out looks like

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\bin\sqlite3cipher.exe" "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\pages\dbdir\testdb"
```

doesn't produce any output. Also the code stops executing, so I assume there's something wrong with the I/O?

---

### Problem

In order to encode a database I want to execute `sqlite3cipher.exe` on the command line in Java.

I ran into quite some diverging results for various approaches. At first the setup (notice that this is a testing environment where right now nothing can be changed regarding where files are located):

- `sqlite3cipher.exe`resides in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\bin\`
- an empty file `testdb`resides in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\pages\dbdir\`
- a file containing SQL statements `statements.sql` resides in the same folder as `testdb` does

Executing `sqlite3cipher.exe -help` on the command line prints the usage. Here is an exerpt:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\bin\sqlite3cipher.exe [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL] 
FILENAME is the name of an SQLite database. A new database is created if the file does not previously exist.
```

Executing `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\bin\sqlite3cipher.exe" "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\pages\dbdir\testdb" < "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\pages\dbdir\statements.sql"` on the command line has the desired effect: `testdb` now is an encrypted database according to the SQL statements that were put in through the `statements.sql`.

Now in Java my code looks like this:

```java
String cmdForRuntime = "cmd /C \"" + prog.getAbsolutePath() + "\" \"" + fDb.getAbsolutePath() + "\" < \"" + fSqlScript.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmdForRuntime );

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String s;

while ((s = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.info("OUTPUT FROM PROG: " + s);
}

if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
    logger.info("Process finished");
}
else {
    logger.error("Error!");

    // Get input streams
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

    System.out.println("Standard error: ");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

where `prog` , `fDb` and `fSqlScript` are of type `File` and represent `sqlite3cipher.exe`, `testdb` and `statements.sql` respectively.

I'm not well versed with `Process.execute()` but what I gathered from reading about it is that `cmd /c` as part of the command is required on Windows (the test server is running Windows 8) in order to start the command interpreter.

On execution this code returns `Access denied` on the command line (via the process's streams). Executing this exact command (including `cmd /c`) on the command line directly returns the same result: `Access denied`. Even if I start the command line as administrator.

Leaving `cmd /c` out of the command (because it had worked without on the **command line** before), I get the message that there are `too many options`.
On further investigation, I learned that this problem is caused by the `<` operator, used in the command to redirect the input. The `exec()` method won't recognize `<` as an operator and it was suggested to use the process's `OutputStream`. So I changed my code to look like this:

```java
String cmdForRuntime = "cmd /c \"" + prog.getAbsolutePath() + "\" \"" + fDb.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmdForRuntime );

BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fSqlScript.getAbsolutePath()));

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String s;
String fileInput = br.readLine();

while (fileInput != null) {

    bufferedwriter.write(fileInput);

    while ((s = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        logger.info("OUTPUT FROM PROG: " + s);
    }

    fileInput = br.readLine();
}

if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
    logger.info("Process finished");
}
else {
    logger.error("Error!");

    // Get input streams
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

    System.out.println("Standard error: ");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

As I understand it is important to read what the external program prints out so it won't block or stop working. That's why I read a line from `statements.sql` (through the `BufferedReader br`) and write it to the process's `OutputStream`. Then I read what the program will print out (logging that output). If there is nothing (left) to read I read the next line from the `statements.sql`. This will be repeated until there is nothing left to read from said file.

If I execute this code, my logger will log the following:

```
INFO  Executing command: cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\bin\sqlite3cipher.exe" "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\pages\dbdir\testdb"
ERROR Error!
Standard error: 
Access denied
```

In this case, the code at least terminates resulting in an empty file `testdb`. In another approach I left `cmd` in the command but skipped the `/c` resulting in following output:

```
INFO  Executing command: cmd "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\bin\sqlite3cipher.exe" "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\pages\dbdir\testdb"
INFO  OUTPUT FROM PROG: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
INFO  OUTPUT FROM PROG: (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
INFO  OUTPUT FROM PROG:
```

The output is the same you get when you type `cmd` on the command line. And that's where execution stops.

---

### tl;dr

- execution on command line directly works like a charm
- exact same command executed from Java doesn't work
- command prepended by `cmd /c` (as it apparently should be) and usage of the process's `InputStream` and `OutputStream` doesn't work: `Access denied`

I'm not sure what to do next, so I sincerely hope someone can help me.

Comment: Why do you think you need the "cmd /C". You don't need the command interperted to execute .exe files. Check this link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java

Comment: I've updated the post. I've omitted `cmd /c` in the command resulting with the execution to stop. No output is read.

Comment: seems like `UAC` issue! is ur program running in `Elevated` mode?

Comment: I've started Tomcat (who then executes said code) in elevated mode. Once with `cmd /c` in the command (again `Access denied`), once without (no output at all and code execution stops).

Comment: Any antivirus running? Try to disable. Can you try in safe mode (I assumed you are using windows)

Comment: As far as I can see there is no anti virus software running. Unfortunately there is no way for me to boot the machine in safe mode.

Comment: Your output logs appear to be inconsistent? In your first one it references locations in `C:\Program Files`, whereas in your second it's `C:\Programme`. Also in your first one there is a space where there probably shouldn't be `C:\ Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\pages\dbdir\testdb`

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I'm working on a German version of Windows so `Program Files` would be `Programme`. Just translated it for this post, so everyone would be on the same page that this is a system folder. What you are actually referring to are in fact my weak copy and editing skills. I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem with the workaround I mentioned in update 3.

My Java code now looks like this (besides the `cmdForRuntime` variable it should be pretty much the same code as in the beginning, when I asked this question):

```
try {
        File fDb = new File(this.inputDirectory + File.separator + dbName);

        String cmdForRuntime =  "\"" + cmdScript.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" + " " +       // the script to be executed 
                                "\"" + prog.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" + " " +            // sqlite3cipher.exe
                                "\"" + fDb.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" + " " +             // testdb
                                "\"" + fSqlScript.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";             // statements.sql

        logger.info("Executing command: " + cmdForRuntime );

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmdForRuntime );

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String s;

        while ((s = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.info("OUTPUT FROM PROG: " + s);
        }

        if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
            logger.info("Process finished");
        }
        else {
            logger.error("!!!! error !!!!");
            // Get input streams
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

            System.out.println("Standard error: ");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`cmdForRuntime` will read something like this (I will omit the paths, the only add to the confusion):

```
"SQLiteCipher.cmd" "sqlite3cipher.exe" "testdb" "statements.sql"
```

The content of the script looks like this:

```
%1 %2 < %3
```

This will invoke the `sqlite3cipher.exe` with the parameter `testdb` and a redirected input coming from `statements.sql`.

Critical is that the location of the script as well as the location of the exe is not a system folder.

If all these criteria are met everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You are having [User Account Control issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

It seems like the program is running in non-elevated mode, to make changes to system directories the application need to run in elevated mode.

Running you program in elevated mode should solve the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've started Tomcat in elevated mode (`Run as administrator`) with the exact same outcome.