# How to get nimbus logs error using java code

Tags: apache-storm

I want to analyze the `error from nimbus logs using java`. Is there any way i can do the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Storm support to do this. I would recommend to write a (bash) script and copy the log files to you local machine and analyze them there. You can also do the copy step within Java by triggering scp command (see [Execute external program in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java))