# Docker stats from java

Tags: java, docker

Please how can I run curl operation for docker-container in Java ?
When I run this command on shell

> docker stats

I got this result

```
> CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM % 
> NET I/O              BLOCK I/O           PIDS 08b45b1e3f56       
> 0.00%               1.453 MiB / 995.9 MiB   0.15%               1.285 kB / 1.92 kB   0 B / 0 B           2
```

For this container

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
08b45b1e3f56        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   agitated_boyd
```

My question is, How can I run this command line (docker stats) from Java program (REST API) and retreive the results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute external program in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker` CLI just calls into the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/).

That's a REST API you can call directly, or use a client wrapper like [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java).