# Can we run festival.exe through java?

Tags: java, cmd, text-to-speech, festival

I am trying to run **festival.exe** through *java*. I tried running the following code but apparently it is not working. Where is it going wrong?

```
    String [] cmdArray= {"C://Festival//festival.exe","(SayText \"Hello\")"};
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec(cmdArray);
```

I have even tried:

```
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\festival\\festival.exe","(SayText \"Hello\")").start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;

    System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", Arrays.toString(args));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
```

This is also giving blank output and not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute external program in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java)

Comment: Use a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: I tried processbuilder but it is also not executing and giving blank output!!

Comment: As said ProcessBuilder. It might be the argument containing both space and double quotes (`"(SayText", "\"Hello\")"`. Maybe that could be given on the command line (PrintStream), or such.

Comment: @JoopEggen it does not work!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling command line process, it's best to use on of [APIs provided by Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/manual/festival_28.html).

Sample Java client can be found here: https://github.com/festvox/festival/blob/master/src/modules/java/cstr/festival/Client.java

Comment: I already saw this! But could not get on how to use it. Could you provide some sample code on how to use it?

Comment: Before running Client.java, please start festival.exe --server. If you run both server and client on the same machine, no further configuration is needed. More info about switches: http://www.festvox.org/docs/manual-2.4.0/festival_7.html.